# Rails: make a nested hash-array type object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I'm trying to make a nested (and thus sorted) array of hashes like so:

```
[{ stack: 'stack name', id: 1,
    boxes: [{
      box: 'whatever box',
      id: 1,
      vars: [{
        var: 'some name',
        id: 22,
      }, 
      { var: 'another name',
        id: 4 
      }]
    }, {
      box: 'another box',
      id: 99,
      vars: [{
        var: 'another',
        id: 999
      }]
    }    
  }]
}]
```

The method I've come up with so far is this which doesn't work but I'm totally stack as to how to *nest* these objects to maintain their hierarchy (a `Stack` can have many `Boxes`, a `Box` can have many `TemplateVariables`.

```
master = []
@template.stacks.alphabetised.each_with_index do |stack, i|
  master << { stack: stack.name, id: stack.id }
  stack.boxes.indexed.each_with_index do |box, j|
    master[i] = { box: box.name, id: box.id }
    box.template_variables.indexed.each do |var|
      master[i][j] = { var: var.name, id: var.id }
    end
  end
end
master
```

This seems to return nothing despite those objects definitely being there (and I know my structure is off, too). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The syntax isn't correct for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested `map`s :

```
################################################
# Initialization code. Different from yours.
def stacks
  Array.new(2){|i| "Stack #{i+1}"}
end

@box_id = 0
def boxes
  Array.new(2){ "Box #{@box_id += 1}"}
end

@var_id = 0
def vars
  Array.new(2){ "Var #{@var_id += 1}"}
end
################################################

stack_data = stacks.map.with_index do |stack,i|
  box_data = boxes.map.with_index do |box,j|
    var_data = vars.map.with_index do |var,k|
      {var: var, id: k}
    end
    {box: box, id: j, vars: var_data}
  end
  {stack: stack, id: i, boxes: box_data}
end

require 'pp'
pp stack_data
```

It outputs :

```
[{:stack=>"Stack 1",
  :id=>0,
  :boxes=>
   [{:box=>"Box 1",
     :id=>0,
     :vars=>[{:var=>"Var 1", :id=>0}, {:var=>"Var 2", :id=>1}]},
    {:box=>"Box 2",
     :id=>1,
     :vars=>[{:var=>"Var 3", :id=>0}, {:var=>"Var 4", :id=>1}]}]},
 {:stack=>"Stack 2",
  :id=>1,
  :boxes=>
   [{:box=>"Box 3",
     :id=>0,
     :vars=>[{:var=>"Var 5", :id=>0}, {:var=>"Var 6", :id=>1}]},
    {:box=>"Box 4",
     :id=>1,
     :vars=>[{:var=>"Var 7", :id=>0}, {:var=>"Var 8", :id=>1}]}]}]
```